# Reduce Integer.min doesn't return lowest element

Tags: java, java-8

I am doing some research on the `stream reduce` and trying to run the very simple program.

Why `Integer.min` doesn't return the minimum number like `Integer.min` return the maximum number ?

```
public class Reducing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(3,4,5,1,2);
        Integer sum = numbers.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a+ b);
        System.out.println("REDUCE : "+sum);

        int sum2 = numbers.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
        System.out.println(sum2);

        int max = numbers.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> Integer.max(a, b));
        System.out.println("MAX == > "+max);

        int min = numbers.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> Integer.min(a, b));
        System.out.println("MIN == > "+min);
    }
}
```

Output ==>

```
REDUCE : 15
15
MAX == > 5
MIN == > 0
```

Comment: Is ` stream().min(Integer::compare).get();` is not enough?

Comment: like `Integer.min` return the maximum number - should be `.max`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are supplying `0` as identity item to `min`. This value will also used in computations.

```
int min = numbers.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> Integer.min(a, b));
```

So virtually it is like having

```
Arrays.asList(0,3,4,5,1,2)
```

You shuold omit the identity element in your example

```
int min = numbers.stream().reduce((a, b) -> Integer.min(a, b)).get();
```

Comment: or use the correct identity value: `.reduce(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer::min)`

Answer (score 5):

You're passing `0` as the initial value into your reduce: `reduce(0, (a, b) -> Integer.min(a, b))`. It's therefore the smallest number. Pass `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead or use the following:

```
Optional<Integer> min = numbers.stream().reduce((a, b) -> Integer.min(a, b));
System.out.println("MIN == > " + min.get());
```

Or, an even without the lambda:

```
Optional<Integer> min = numbers.stream().reduce(Integer::min)
```

There's also an option of doing it reduce.and using `min` instead:

```
Optional<Integer> min = numbers.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Comment: What if I dont want to pass 0 as initial, how can I modify the code in that case. I only want lowest element from the array

Comment: Use the version of `reduce` without the initial value. I've added an example.

Answer (score 3):

the `reduce` operation works as:
you have this list:

```
Arrays.asList(3,4,5,1,2);
```

and do

```
reduce(0, (a, b) -> Integer.max(a, b));
```

which means:

compare all  the pair a, b and the first element must 0 as precesor

so the operation will be

```
Integer.max(a, b)
Integer.max(0, 3) => return  3
Integer.max(3, 4) => return  4
Integer.max(4, 5) => return  5
Integer.max(5, 1) => return  5
Integer.max(5, 2) => return  5
```

and for the min, the same analogy applies...

```
Integer.min(a, b)

Integer.min(0, 3) => return  0
Integer.min(0, 4) => return  0
Integer.min(0, 5) => return  0
Integer.min(0, 1) => return  0
Integer.min(0, 2) => return  0
```

thus the result max:5 and min:0

Answer (score 0):

The reduce operation in this example takes two arguments:

identity: The identity element is both the initial value of the reduction and the default result if there are no elements in the stream. In this example, the identity element is 0; this is the initial value of the sum of ages and the default value if no members exist in the collection roster.

Use `numbers.get(0)` instead of 0, so the initial value would be the first item in your list

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to use below. Optional is a container object which is used to contain not-null objects. Optional object is used to represent null with absent value. ... It is introduced in Java 8 and is similar to what Optional is in Guava.

```
Optional<Integer> min = numbers.stream().reduce(Integer::min);
min.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Here is the oracle article : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Answer (score 0):

The `reduce` method takes the `identity` - the first argument, 0 in your case, in consideration while applying the given `reduction` function. The supplied identity acts as both an **initial value** and a default value.

As per the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), `reduce` works on the following algorithm:

> ```
> T result = identity;
>  for (T element : this stream)
>      result = accumulator.apply(result, element)
>  return result;
> ```

Hence, while evaluating the `Integer.min`, the value of 0 is also included in the calculation.

A solution is to not supply any identity or an identity that is greater than or equal to the smallest value in the list.